# Copy and paste text into an Oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, copy-paste

In SQL Server, you can copy an Excel spreadsheet, go to SQL Server, open a table, highlight the last row and Ctrl+V to paste all the records from Excel into SQL.

Is there a way to do this in Oracle?  I don't want to *import*, I want to *copy & paste*.  It doesn't appear to let me do it.

Please note; my experience with Oracle is a whopping 3 hours.  One of those, "Oh, we're switching to Oracle today.  Learn it or find a new job" things.  So feel free to explain your answer as if I'm a complete Oracle n00b, because I am.

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.  According to the Help, it's Version 4.1.3.20

Comment: You mean like this? [Copy & Paste Imports from Excel to Oracle using SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/07/copy-paste-imports-from-excel-to-oracle-using-sql-developer/)

Comment: So you have to physically add a row for every row you're copying.  Not bad when you're bringing in 10 rows, big-time bummer when you're bringing in 10,000.  Oh well.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: thats what import is for.

Answer (score 0):

click the table. in the window on the right there should be a data tab. click it. there will be an insert row tab. click the field you want to paste to click control+v then click the commit button

Make sure what you are copying is the right data type for the field you are copying into. Since you have sql experience this should help.

It should be noted this is not the preferred way to do this, you should use insert statements.